# ruby on rails how to access left join variables from view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, join

My Index Controller:

```
class IndexController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @posts = Post.find(:all, :limit => 10,
                            :joins => "LEFT JOIN `users` ON users.user_id = posts.user_id",
                            :select => "posts.*, users.username",
                            :order => "posts.created_at DESC")
    end
end
```

How can i access the users.username from the view?

I tried

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <%= post.username %>
<% end %>
```

but it doesn't seem to work since i get a blank message...

**EDIT:**

i had to use the following code in the LEFT JOIN:

```
:joins => "LEFT JOIN `users` ON posts.user_id = users.id",
```

Comment: does `@post.user.username` work?

Comment: @x1a4 i get `undefined method `user' for #<Post:0x4281918>`

Comment: Do you have an association between Posts and Users? It looks like you have the database setup already, and if that's the case, it's a 1 line update to your `Post` model to add the association.

Comment: @x1a4 i guess i dont... how can i do that? i already have user_id on users and posts tables

Comment: in the case, it looks like all you would need is the line `belongs_to :user` in your `Post` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had to use the following code in the LEFT JOIN:

```
:joins => "LEFT JOIN `users` ON posts.user_id = users.id",
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ..

```
@posts = Post.find(:all, :limit => 10,
                            :joins => "LEFT JOIN `users` ON users.user_id = posts.user_id",
                            :select => "posts.*, users.username as user_name",
                            :order => "posts.created_at DESC")


<% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <%= post.user_name %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: user_name gives a blank message instead of the correct username... weird

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not MVC friendly. This is how its better done in Rails.

**1. Your models should do the queries:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  scope :last_10, order("created_at desc").limit(10) #or "id desc" which is quicker
end
```

**2. Call the query in the controller**

```
class IndexController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @posts = User.find_by_username(the_username).posts.last_10
  end
end
```

**3. Then you could do, in your view**

```
<% @posts.each do |p| %>
  <%= post.user.username %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I added the view part. There is also other ways to do it if you want to force usage of `joins` or do the posts query from the user model. It's better not to use queries in the controller. The controller job is to get the request, call the models then render the right view with the results.